# How to use JSON from db/php in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a map plugin to render some data. The data comes from the DB and into a json file - the script works great. I decided to use the data directly from the php output instead of making a json file. For some reason the javaScript doesn't accept the direct php input. I'm using codeigniter MVC

Here is the sample code that currently works:

```
$.getJSON('_data/index/data.json', function(data){ ...
```

Here is what I tried:

```
 var dataMap = '<? print $mapData;?>';
        $.getJSON(dataMap, function(data){...
```

*** EDIT 2 ***

Based on the answers - this option doesn't work either.

```
var dataMap = '<?php echo $mapData;?>';
        $.get(dataMap, function(data){...
```

And here is the json data

```
{"countries":{"AL":"1","GB":"1","RS":"1","BG":"6","CA":"3","AT":"2","CD":"1"}}
```

***EDIT***

$mapData is

```
FOREACH LOOP
 $retdata['countries'][] = strtoupper($row->code);
 $retdata['num'][] = $row->num;
ENDFOREACH LOOP
 $retdata['countries'] = array_combine($retdat['code'], $retdata['num']);
 $retdata = json_encode($retdata);
```

And then it is printed into a file as normal. This is into the model, then I pass it to the controller and then into the view. The string is the same in the `$dataMap` that I have on file and the one that is being sent to the view.

Comment: Try echo:  `var dataMap = '<? echo $mapData;?>';`

Comment: Can you show us what `$mapData` is?  `$.getJSON` is a shortcut for an ajax request to the server.  i.e. it should be a path/url to something which returns json data.

Comment: the print_r($mapData) is the same as the json data above. When I use echo the console adds the json to the link and prints a 403 (Forbidden) jquery.min.js:2

Comment: Added more info regarding the $mapData and how I create it.

Comment: Great, looks like you can just use $mapData directly as it's already a json string

Comment: as an alternative you can do the json encode on the javascript assignment directly: `var dataMap = <?php echo json_encode($mapData) ?>;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just going to directly insert your JSON data into a javascript variable (rather than using AJAX), then you shouldn't need a `getJSON` call at all. Just write the object directly like this.

```
var js_object = <?php echo $mapData; ?>;
alert(js_object.countries.AL);
alert(js_object.countries.GB);
```

Note that the PHP string is not echoed into enclosing quotes, this means you are directly creating a javascript object literal, not a string that then needs to be parsed into an object via `JSON.parse()`

Comment: I guess I am not following what you are trying to do.  You don't need any `get` or `getJSON` at all if you just inject the JSON object into a javascript variable when creating the page source.  You can then use this object in whatever function you want. See my update answer for example of how to use the object.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from your updated code, it looks like you don't need to call `getJSON` at all as you already have json data.

Simply take `<? echo $mapData;?>` and assign it to a variable in your javascript code and use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use dataMap as a JSON directly.

```
alert(dataMap.countries.AL); //output: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the given answers *do* work, you might want to implement it differently so your code is easier to maintain.

You could have a controller that handles all your api calls, and place all your map-related functions there.

If your controller is called `maps` and you create a `countries` method that fetches from the database and returns a json with the countries, then in your JS you could do:

```
$.get('maps/countries', function(data){
  console.log(data.countries);
  //outputs: {"AL":"1","GB":"1","RS":"1","BG":"6","CA":"3","AT":"2","CD":"1"}
};
```

More on [CI Controllers](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)